# PlayFramework HTTPS routes only in prod mode, HTTP in dev mode

Tags: playframework

I would like certain routes to always be HTTPS when in production mode, but HTTP in development mode.  Right now, the only way I'm aware of creating https routes is using:
`@@{Controller.action().secure()}`, but that hard-codes them to be https.

Is this possible in the routes or with a application.conf setting?

Answer (score 5):

The only easy way to change the way this works from Dev to Prod mode, is by leaving Play in HTTP only, and then securing your whole site in Prod mode by fronting it with an HTTP server like NGinx, Lighttp or Apache.

This approach means that your application stays the same in both modes, and the configuration is done at a higher layer than your application.

This approach however will mean your *entire* site will become HTTPS, but I don't actually see this as being a bad thing, in fact it may give your users a little more confidence in the security of your entire site.

Comment: +1 for all HTTPS.  If you have a cookie for running a session over HTTP, it's a one-click hijack on most WiFi networks.

Comment: But what about environments with mixed HTTP and HTTPS parts? One approach would be to force a specific part of the application (e.g. "/secure/...") to https and let the rest of the application use http. (with the help of a front proxy like Nginx) That works fine unless I haven't found a solution for rendering URLs in the templates with a given scheme depending on the part of the application I'm in. (reverse routing with a given scheme definition)

Comment: of course, if you are in the amazon environment, I hear/read performance on https is horrible if you have their ELB load balancers terminating it and it is much better if you terminate the https at your webserver (lots of tradeoffs I guess)....if you already have 10 webservers at amazon, better to terminate there as the you don't want to end up with 10 ELB's just because you have https enabled.